# Why are instances of duplicated groups linked

Tags: groups, instances

I'm a bit of a newb, so please bear with me.
I have a number of objects (chairs) that are parented to another object (table). I have created a group of these objects and have many instances of this group. I was hoping to be able to duplicate the original group of table and chairs as I want to make slight adjustments to the duplicated group and in turn make instances of this new group.

However, once the group is duplicated there appears to be a link between the first instance of the first group and the first instance of the second group, so if I delete an instance from the second group, then it will also be deleted from the first group. Is there a way to duplicate the first group so I can modify the elements of the second group without it effecting the first group.
Thanks in advance.
Russ

Answer (score 1):

An object can be a member of more than one group, they are more like tags or lists of objects than "groups" in the more traditional sense. So if I'm understanding your post correctly, you can make a group for the first table/chair set, then another one for the second set. Any objects you want in both sets, just add them to both groups.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It's not so much that I want to include an object in more than one group - it's more like I want to duplicate a group (and it's instances) and then tweak this second group, so that all of it's instances change as well. The only problem seems to be that whatever I do to the second group, also happens to the first group. Say

Comment: for instance the chair's back in group 1 is square (and of course all of it's instances have square backs). I duplicate group 1 to make group 2. I want group 2, (and all of its instances ) to have round backs. But when I alter the back in group 2, group 1 changes as well. when I make the instance real, in group 2, then the corresponding instance in group 1 is also made real. I want to be able to alter group 2 without effecting group 1.

Comment: To do that, you'd need to make a copy of the chair with the round back, and put that in group 2 in place of the square-backed chair.

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed, these are indeed instances linked to the original, which is why they are called "[Group Instances](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/objects/duplication/dupligroup.html)".

You can, however, Make the DupliGroup objects real using the keys: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

This will make each of the objects in the duplicated group separate and unlink these objects from the original group. The new objects will no longer be part of any group, and will no longer be parented to the empty that controlled the group instance.